# Get/Set the index of the last opened li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an accordion and trying to achieve the below:

Every time there is a post back, display/expand the last opened/active li that was shown before. At the moment, the page is refreshed and go back to its initial stage (all li closed). Is it possible to achieve this ?

I tried different things but without success e.g. I tried to save the last opened/active li index into a hidden aspx text box but it didn't work. Also, I tried to save the index in a cookie but again without success.

```
$('#st-accordion').accordion({
                    open: -1
                });
```

Can I replace the -1 with a dynamic way of getting the index of the last opened li without losing it after post back ? In addition, how can I handle situations that more than one li were opened/expanded.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.accordion.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelForm" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <h2><asp:Label ID="TitleLbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h2>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="st-accordion" class="st-accordion">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Section 1<span class="st-arrow" /></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                            Content 1
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Section 2<span class="st-arrow" /></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
                             Content 2
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Section 3<span class="st-arrow" /></a>
                        <div class="st-content">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEdit" OnClick="LinkButtonEdit_Click" CommandName="Select" runat="server">Edit</asp:LinkButton>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#st-accordion').accordion({
                    open: -1
                });

            });
        }
    </script>

(function (window, $, undefined) {

    /*
    * smartresize: debounced resize event for jQuery
    *
    *
    * Copyright 2011 @louis_remi
    * Licensed under the MIT license.
    */

    var $event = $.event, resizeTimeout;

    $event.special.smartresize  = {
        setup: function() {
            $(this).bind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
        },
        teardown: function() {
            $(this).unbind( "resize", $event.special.smartresize.handler );
        },
        handler: function( event, execAsap ) {
            // Save the context
            var context = this,
                args    = arguments;

            // set correct event type
            event.type = "smartresize";

            if ( resizeTimeout ) { clearTimeout( resizeTimeout ); }
            resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                jQuery.event.handle.apply( context, args );
            }, execAsap === "execAsap"? 0 : 100 );
        }
    };

    $.fn.smartresize            = function( fn ) {
        return fn ? this.bind( "smartresize", fn ) : this.trigger( "smartresize", ["execAsap"] );
    };

    $.Accordion                 = function( options, element ) {

        this.$el            = $( element );
        // list items
        this.$items         = this.$el.children('ul').children('li');
        // total number of items
        this.itemsCount     = this.$items.length;

        // initialize accordion
        this._init( options );

    };

    $.Accordion.defaults        = {
        // index of opened item. -1 means all are closed by default.
        open            : -1,
        // if set to true, only one item can be opened. Once one item is opened, any other that is opened will be closed first
        oneOpenedItem   : false,
        // speed of the open / close item animation
        speed           : 600,
        // easing of the open / close item animation
        easing          : 'easeInOutExpo',
        // speed of the scroll to action animation
        scrollSpeed     : 900,
        // easing of the scroll to action animation
        scrollEasing: 'easeInOutExpo'
    };

    $.Accordion.prototype       = {
        _init               : function( options ) {

            this.options        = $.extend( true, {}, $.Accordion.defaults, options );

            // validate options
            this._validate();

            // current is the index of the opened item
            this.current        = this.options.open;

            // hide the contents so we can fade it in afterwards
            this.$items.find('div.st-content').hide();

            // save original height and top of each item    
            this._saveDimValues();

            // if we want a default opened item...
            if( this.current != -1 )
                this._toggleItem( this.$items.eq( this.current ) );

            // initialize the events
            this._initEvents();

        },
        _saveDimValues      : function() {

            this.$items.each( function() {

                var $item       = $(this);

                $item.data({
                    originalHeight  : $item.find('a:first').height(),
                    offsetTop       : $item.offset().top
                });

            });

        },
        // validate options
        _validate           : function() {

            // open must be between -1 and total number of items, otherwise we set it to -1
            if( this.options.open < -1 || this.options.open > this.itemsCount - 1 )
                this.options.open = -1;

        },
        _initEvents         : function() {

            var instance    = this;

            // open / close item
            this.$items.find('a:first').bind('click.accordion', function( event ) {

                var $item           = $(this).parent();

                // close any opened item if oneOpenedItem is true
                if( instance.options.oneOpenedItem && instance._isOpened() && instance.current!== $item.index() ) {

                    instance._toggleItem( instance.$items.eq( instance.current ) );

                }

                // open / close item
                instance._toggleItem( $item );

                return false;

            });

            $(window).bind('smartresize.accordion', function( event ) {

                // reset orinal item values
                instance._saveDimValues();

                // reset the content's height of any item that is currently opened
                instance.$el.find('li.st-open').each( function() {

                    var $this   = $(this);
                    $this.css( 'height', $this.data( 'originalHeight' ) + $this.find('div.st-content').outerHeight( true ) );

                });

                // scroll to current
                //if( instance._isOpened() )
                    //instance._scroll();
            });

        },
        // checks if there is any opened item
        _isOpened           : function() {

            return ( this.$el.find('li.st-open').length > 0 );

        },
        // open / close item
        _toggleItem         : function( $item ) {

            var $content = $item.find('div.st-content');

            ( $item.hasClass( 'st-open' ) ) 

                ? ( this.current = -1, $content.stop(true, true).fadeOut( this.options.speed ), $item.removeClass( 'st-open' ).stop().animate({
                    height  : $item.data( 'originalHeight' )
                }, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ) )

                : ( this.current = $item.index(), $content.stop(true, true).fadeIn( this.options.speed ), $item.addClass( 'st-open' ).stop().animate({
                    height  : $item.data( 'originalHeight' ) + $content.outerHeight( true )
                }, this.options.speed, this.options.easing ), this._scroll( this ) )

        },
        // scrolls to current item or last opened item if current is -1
        _scroll             : function( instance ) {

            var instance    = instance || this, current;

            ( instance.current !== -1 ) ? current = instance.current : current = instance.$el.find('li.st-open:last').index();

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrolltop   : ( instance.options.oneopeneditem ) ? instance.$items.eq( current ).data( 'offsettop' ) : instance.$items.eq( current ).offset().top
            }, instance.options.scrollspeed, instance.options.scrolleasing );

        }
    };

    var logError = function( message ) {

        if ( this.console ) {

            console.error( message );

        }

    };

    $.fn.accordion= function( options ) {

        if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

            this.each(function() {

                var instance = $.data( this, 'accordion' );

                if ( !instance ) {
                    logError( "cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; " +
                    "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                    return;
                }

                if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {
                    logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for accordion instance" );
                    return;
                }

                instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

            });

        } 
        else {

            this.each(function() {
                var instance = $.data( this, 'accordion' );
                if ( !instance ) {
                    $.data( this, 'accordion', new $.Accordion( options, this ) );
                }
            });

        }

        return this;

    };

        })(window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage in order to save some js variables with the last opened/expanded li, you can set it on open/expand event:

```
sessionStorage.SessionName = "SessionName";

sessionStorage.getItem("SessionName");

sessionStorage.setItem("SessionName","10");
```

Or you can use cookies (client side):

```
document.cookie
```

Comment: After the post back, previous opened <li> does not yet open

Comment: You need to set your logic, like on page load check if the target <li> has active class or something like this.